# Is the sequence $f_n(x) = n(\sqrt [n]{x}-1)$ converges uniformly on $[1,a]$ where $a >1$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is   the sequence $f_n(x) = n(\sqrt [n]{x}-1)$ converges  uniformly on $[1,a]$  where $a >1$ ?

**My attempt:** I was thinking about $M_n$ test 
$$M_n = \sup_{x \in [1,a]} | n( \sqrt [n]x-1)- 0|=\sup_{x \in [1,a]} |n(e^{\frac{1}{n}\log x} -1)- 0|$$
After that  i can not able to proceed further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The pointwise limit in $[1,a]$ is $\ln(x)$ (it is not $0$):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^{\ln(x)/n}-1}{1/n}=\ln(x).$$
Hence, following your approach, you should consider 
$$\sup_{x \in [1,a]} |n(e^{\ln(x)/n} -1)- \ln(x)|=
n\sup_{t \in [0,\frac{\ln(a)}{n}]} |e^{t} -1- t|.$$
Can you take it from here?

Alternatively, you may that for any $x\in [1,a]$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing. Then use the [Dini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).

Comment: thanks @Robert   oh  yaa  i misses that...but   $\sup_{x \in [1,a]} |e^{\frac{1}{n}\log x} -1)-  \ logx|$.... how  can i proceed further??

Comment: @stupid See my edit.

Comment: thanksu    @Robert